# setup:upgrade command when create controller

Tags: magento2

I'm creating controller in existing module but when I write url I got 404 not found

should I run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` when I add a controller or there is any other command to run?

Comment: just wanted to confirm have you added routes.xml ?

Comment: yes, I added it